# Difference between mod_auth_ldap and mod_authnz_ldap

Tags: svn, apache2, ldap

We use LDAP for Subversion access using Apache httpd. We originally had all of our Subversion repositories accessible by all users using the following:

```
<Location /src>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /opt/svn_repos
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "SVN Repository"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.mycorp.com:3268/dc=mycorp,dc=com?sAMAccountName" NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=svn_acct,OU=Users,DC=mycorp,DC=com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "swordfish"
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Everything was fine. I was asked to move the CM repository to a different location, and make it accessible for only people in the CM group. I did the following:

```
<Location /cm>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /opt/cm_svn_repos
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "CM Repository"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.mycorp.com:3268/dc=mycorp,dc=com?sAMAccountName" NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=svn_acct,OU=Users,DC=mycorp,DC=com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "swordfish"
    Require group CN=cm-group,OU=Groups,DC=mycorp,DC=com
</Location>
```

I spent a couple of hours on this before realizing that I was using mod_auth***nz***_ldap and not plain ol' mod_auth_ldap. Thus, I needed `ldap-group` instead of `group` in my `Require` statement. That worked.

My coworker informed me that there was a reason why we used mod_auth**nz**_ldap and not mod_auth_ldap, but he couldn't remember why. We looked up the Apache httpd documentation, but the documentation provides no clues why you'd use one over the other.

So, what is the difference between mod_auth_ldap and mod_auth**nz**_ldap, and why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Anyone else who came across this question. It has to do with the newer versions of Apache httpd. My confusion stemmed from the changes between version 2.1 and 2.2 of httpd. Since I had Apache 2.2, I was suppose to use the new framework:

- `mod_auth_ldap` is for Apache versions before 2.2
- `mod_authnz_ldap` is for Apache versions 2.2 and later.

---

## From the [Apache 2.2 Manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_2.html)

### Module Enhancements

#### Authn/Authz

> Modules in the aaa directory have been renamed and offer better support for digest authentication. For example, `mod_auth` is now split into `mod_auth_basic` and `mod_authn_file`; `mod_auth_dbm` is now called `mod_authn_dbm`; `mod_access` has been renamed `mod_authz_host`. There is also a new `mod_authn_alias` (already removed from 2.3/2.4) module for simplifying certain authentication configurations.

#### mod_authnz_ldap

> This module is a port of the 2.0 mod_auth_ldap module to the 2.2 Authn/Authz framework. New features include using LDAP attribute values and complicated search filters in the Require directive.

### Module Developer Changes

#### Authn/Authz

> The bundled authentication and authorization modules have been renamed along the following lines:
>
> - `mod_auth_*` -> Modules that implement an HTTP authentication mechanism
> - `mod_authn_*` -> Modules that provide a backend authentication provider
> - `mod_authz_*` -> Modules that implement authorization (or access)
> - `mod_authnz_*` -> Module that implements both authentication & authorization